# How to Database-Sent Events

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Everyone is talking about sending events related to an agent and is related to the time of update of the action. The search get is when you add a new entry to a table in the database. Get events on the `Response.Flush()` method , and I want to take advantage of this technique without actually resorting to functions.
Is this function made in the controller or within the database within the trigger
But within Asp.Net I can not activate them and take advantage of them.
I hope to find what I aspire to in this prestigious platform.

Comment: Your question is completely unclear. Can you please add some more details of what you actually want to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at SqlDependency:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/detecting-changes-with-sqldependency

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/query-notifications-in-sql-server

It's a mechanism where your sqlclient code subscribes to events previously configured at the SQL-Server level, then it gets invoked when a change occurs. It's not trivial; you're going to have to research a bit, but that should get you going.